# I want to remove the register/login Wordpress top bar from my website

Tags: plugins, php, customization, user-registration, buddypress

[image]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U0guO.jpg),

This screenshot above shows the `functions.php` *code* snippet I tried to use to remove WordPress register/login top bar from my website but so far it haven’t worked. I included the *code* into a Wordpress plugin called *code* snippets.

(I included the custom *code* to *code* snippet Wordpress plugin because I wanted to to add content to my themes `functions.php` file without directly editing my themes files)

Please advise how I can get this *code* to work and remove Wordpress user register/login top bar from my website

Thanks..

Comment: What does the bar look like? Are you sure it’s the admin bar and not part of your theme?

Comment: Is your site hosted on wordpress.com/pressable? If it doesn't work, what does it do instead?

Answer (score -1):

you can use this

```
add_action('after_setup_theme', 'remove_admin_bar');
function remove_admin_bar() {
    if (!current_user_can('administrator') && !is_admin()) {
        show_admin_bar(false);
    }
}
```